Ports & adapters a.k.a hexagonal architecture modeling interfaces
I'm designing architecture for my small project. Java, spring-boot powered.
The idea behind this application is simple - retrieve some decision based on input parameters and external api.
I think that the architecture looks like follow:
- org
-- example
--- someapp
---- adapters
----- ...
---- domain
----- BusinessDecision.java
---- ports
----- driver
------ ForRetreivingBusinessDecision.java
----- driven
------ ForRetreivingExternalInfo.java

The real question is if ForRetreivingBusinessDecision.java should contain BusinessDecision getDecision(String input1, String input2); or the return value should be void and in the adapters side I should somehow produce the response object? Or it should be String as it will be managed in adapters as a JSON response?
If it is question for different stack network then I'm sorry.

By the way, “driving” might be a better word choice as “driver” has other meanings in computing.

The hexagonal architecture is also known as the ports and adapters, because they are the core concepts.

Ports abstract communication (in and out). They are there to protect the application inner state and its domain representation from the outside.
Adapters implement the concrete communication protocol. They are the translator between the outside and inside world.

So, each adapter depends on a single port. That also means a single port can have many adapters. For instance a single in port can have a REST API, a WebSocket and a gRPC adapters.
Your ForRetreivingBusinessDecision object should be communication technology agnostic. Like it should not include HTTP Status Code and should not be serialized into JSON format. Your adapters' responsibility is to translate your application response into a communication technology specify result.
